# wordpress: display 2 posts on static frontpage + page navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a static frontpage with a little content on it and want to display the blogposts underneath the static content.

The loop is supposed to always display only 2 posts, but it has to be possible to navigate to older posts via WP_PageNavi (a Plugin I always use).

I made a static page my frontpage and added WP_Query underneath the static content. Problem is, it doesn't work because it displays only the latest two posts.

It looks like this:

```
<!-- here goes the static content stuff -->

<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>  

<div class="news">
    <ul>
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_status' => 'publish', 'post__not_in' => $current_id));
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li class="news-post">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></a></p>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { ?>
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>  
    <div class="news">
        <ul>
            <?php 
                 $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

                $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged);


                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                <li class="news-post">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></a></p>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>

        <?php 
            if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')):
                 wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' =>$my_query));
               endif; 
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the PageNavi does not work, it doesn't navigate to other posts but stays on the same page displaying the same posts.

Comment: yes i have change this code after testing in my web. so that work thanks.

Comment: how would you solve that for a single page website?
I have a blog section and want to do the exactly same thing here, but I ask myself how the if-condition is... i guess you can't use if is_front_page here, right? because the whole website is the frontpage.